# Rails 5.2.0 app Webpacker requires Yarn ">=1 <2" and you are using Yarn v0.1.1 2011, elastic beanstalk deployment failed

Tags: amazon-ec2, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
Webpacker requires Yarn ">=1 <2" and you are using Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
Please upgrade Yarn https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
Exiting!

2021/03/03 05:06:35.767452 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/03/03 05:06:35.769905 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1614747995,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2021/03/03 05:06:35.770091 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-237 log]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using `Docker` you should put these lines on your `Dockerfile` before the `RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install ....` part:

```
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```